# "This will help us ensure" or "This will help us TO ensure": use of TO with infinitival clauses

Tags: catenative-verbs

Could you please tell me which sentence correctly uses "to"? I am always a little confused when using "to" in a sentence.

Here, if it is a verb then "to" is required.

> This will help us **to ensure** that

or

> This will help us **ensure** that

Comment: Another related question: [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This will **help** us [**to** ensure that].

With the verb **help**, it is okay either to use or not to use **to**. The part in brackets is called an *infinitival clause*, and when we don't use **to**, it's called a *bare infinitival*:

> This will **help** us [ensure that.]

The verb **help** is called a *catenative verb*: it can be "connected" to another verb ("ensure").

There is a tendency with some speakers to drop **to** when help is more direct, and to retain **to** when help is less direct:

> She **helped** me (*to*) **prepare** my homework by disassembling my computer, so that I had nothing to do but study. (the help is indirect)

---

There are not a lot of catenative verbs that always take "bare infinitivals":

1. Modal verbs (will, shall, can..) and supportive **do**:

> I **can** ensure that. He **did** ensure that.

2. Sensory perception verbs (feel, hear, notice, see, watch, observe, overhear)

> I **saw** him steal the car.
> I **felt** my heart sink.

3. Some of the causative verbs: *have, let, make*:

> I **let** them **play** in my backyard.
>
> His silly poem **made** her **smile**.

And there are several verbs that can take either a "bare infinitival" or a "to-infinitival": *ought, dare, (had/have) known, help*:

> I **had never known** him (to) **lose his temper** before he fell ill. (**know** can take the bare infinitival only is this specific sense and when it is in the Perfect Tense)
>
> Audacious tyrant, do you **dare** *to* **beard** a maiden in her lair! How **dare** you **challenge** me! (with and without "to")

---

And one additional point:

When the matrix ("main") clause is in the Passive Voice, we use **to**, even with the catenative verbs I've just mentioned:

> He was made **to** swear allegiance to the King.
>
> He was heard **to** cry out in protest. "No. Not in the Bible. With respect, Your Grace, I ask to speak on this absolute impediment, please."
>
> The player was seen **to** leave the field.

---

Reference:

- Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Chapter 14, 5.6.2 "Bare Infinitivals"
- [When to use the bare infinitive in catenative constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46931/48335) - a great answer at ELU